# What is the easiest way to create 3 arrays using the code below?

Tags: java

//I really need help creating three arrays using the code below as if it were for three different customers.

```
float taxAmount = (float) (0.0675 * bill);
float totalWithTax = bill + taxAmount;
float tipAmount = (float) (totalWithTax * 0.20);
float grandTotal = totalWithTax + tipAmount;

//Display it back to the user
//System.out.println("meal: $" + charge);
System.out.println("tax: $" + taxAmount);
System.out.println("meal + tax: $" + totalWithTax);
System.out.println("total cost(tip included): $" + grandTotal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them into a `class`

```
class Customer {

   public float taxAmount;
   public float totalWithTax;
   public float tipAmount;
   public float grandTotal;
}
```

now make a array of `Customer`

```
 Customer arr[] = new Customer[3];
```

This is called [array of Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).

now assign there values as follows

```
arr[0].taxAmount = (float) (0.0675 * bill);
arr[1].taxAmount = (float) (0.0675 * bill);
arr[2].taxAmount = (float) (0.0675 * bill);
.
.
.
.
```

Better is to make a `for loop` and then assign them